# Telethon: How do I speed up button clicks within multiple levels

Tags: telethon

I'm creating a simple Python script that interfaces with a Telegram bot.

My objective is to click on inline buttons three levels deep, i.e.:

- Chat (level1)

  - Open (level2)

    - New (level3)

The following code works, however there's a giant delay between the "button clicks":

```
async def main():

    # Reset bot / show the first screen
    await client.send_message('bot_name', '/initiate')
    
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

    # Level 1
    level1 = await client.get_messages('bot_name')
    # Click on button within the first level ("Chat")
    await level1[0].click(6, 0)
    
    # ---- Fast click flow until this point ----

    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

    # Level 2
    level2 = await client.get_messages('bot_name')
    # Click on button within the second level ("Open")
    await level2[0].click(0, 0)

    ...
```

Is there any way to speed up the flow of these clicks?

Thanks

### UPDATE

It seems the /initiate and first click is fast, however I can't figure out how to speed up the click on subsequent levels

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70815784/13827229) can help you.

Comment: Thank you, that covers this issue. Basically, there's no fix.